# How to upload a image in quasar and save into MySQL through Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file-upload, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using Laravel with quasar. How to save a image in file field into a folder in Laravel and image name into mysql database through Laravel controller and model?

```
<q-file
    name="poster_file"
    v-model="item.image"
    outlined
    label="Image"
  />
```